# How to remove gesture recognizer in specific area? TicTacToe

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am only using one tapGesture Recognizer and saying that if its tapped inside a certain label then change the text. However after it is tapped I don't want the labels text to be able to be changed. Here is the function:

```
@IBAction func onTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Here")
        let selectedPoint = sender.locationInView(self.view)
        print(selectedPoint)
        for label in labelArray{
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label1.frame, selectedPoint){
                label1.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            else{
                label1.userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label2.frame, selectedPoint){
                label2.text = String(currentLetter)

            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label3.frame, selectedPoint){
                label3.text = String(currentLetter)


            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label4.frame, selectedPoint){
                label4.text = String(currentLetter)


            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label5.frame, selectedPoint){
                label5.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label6.frame, selectedPoint){
                label6.text = String(currentLetter)

            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label7.frame, selectedPoint){
                label7.text = String(currentLetter)

            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label8.frame, selectedPoint){
                label8.text = String(currentLetter)

            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label9.frame, selectedPoint){
                label9.text = String(currentLetter)

            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label10.frame, selectedPoint){
                label10.text = String(currentLetter)


            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it doesn't seems like a really good way to achieve this, nevertheless, if you deactivate **User Interaction for your label**, right after setting the text, you my think you are done. As this view is over the other and won't let the parent view get to know about the gesture.

> But, that's not how things works

for example:

```
/.../
if CGRectContainsPoint(label9.frame, selectedPoint){
                label9.text = String(currentLetter)
                label9.userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
/.../
```

will do **nothing at all**, instead, this could be a better approach:

```
@IBAction func onTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let selectedPoint = sender.locationInView(self.view)
        for label in labelArray {
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label.frame, selectedPoint){
                if label.text == "" {
                   label.text = String(currentLetter)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Notice that this isn't either the best solution, you should be able to separate **logic** from **view**, but for your question, this will do the trick.

> **FOOTNOTE:**
>
> Notice that in your code, your are traversing an array of labels, but
>   you are not using the `label` identifier, take a close look at how you
>   should be using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `@IBOutlet` for the `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your class and just disable the user interaction after some condition, in your case after it enters inside in one of your `if` clauses using the property `enabled` this disable the swipes interaction in your `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Something like this code:

```
@IBOutlet var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!

@IBAction func onTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   if condition {
        self.tapGesture.enabled = false
   } 
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks, this is a tapGestureRecognizer action I tried the else statement as you can see in the code any other suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @Johnd my mistake, `@IBOutlet` see my updated answer

Comment: The tap gesture recognizer is the entire screen. So disabling it wouldn't work.

Comment: if I wanted a tap gesture for all 9 labels how do you do that?

Comment: I think you can't, what you can do is embedded all the `UILabels` inside a `UIView` set the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UIView` and then calculates the region relative to each `UILabel` from its frame adn know who has be tapped.